# React Native, using Magento 2 REST API.

Tags: javascript, rest, magento, react-native, magento2

So I have an e-commerce site set up using Magento 2 on my localhost. I want to request admin token from Magento through REST API in React Native. I tried using the fetch method but I am not able to proceed and I keep getting an error. I tried to request the same thing from a different REST client and its working there. The error is

```
    Network request failed
onerror
    E:\Javascript\React Native\TestApp02\TestApp03\node_modules\whatwg-fetch\fetch.js:441:29
dispatchEvent
    E:\Javascript\React Native\TestApp02\TestApp03\node_modules\event-target-shim\lib\event-target.js:172:43
setReadyState
    E:\Javascript\React Native\TestApp02\TestApp03\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:567:29
__didCompleteResponse
    E:\Javascript\React Native\TestApp02\TestApp03\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:397:25
<unknown>
    E:\Javascript\React Native\TestApp02\TestApp03\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:503:16
emit
    E:\Javascript\React Native\TestApp02\TestApp03\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:180:12
__callFunction
    E:\Javascript\React Native\TestApp02\TestApp03\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:351:47
<unknown>
    E:\Javascript\React Native\TestApp02\TestApp03\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:116:26
__guardSafe
    E:\Javascript\React Native\TestApp02\TestApp03\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:314:6
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
    E:\Javascript\React Native\TestApp02\TestApp03\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:115:17
```

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Text, View  } from 'react-native';

export default class FetchExample extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={ isLoading: true}
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    return fetch('http://localhost/magento/rest/V1/integration/admin/token', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "username": "RED_KAY",
            "password": "KGAMER30",
        }),    
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: JSON.stringify(responseJson),
        }, function(){

        });

      })
      .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
  render(){

    if(this.state.isLoading){
      return(
        <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 20}}>
          <ActivityIndicator/>
        </View>
      )
    }

    return(
      <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop:20}}>
        <Text> {this.state.dataSource} </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I tried searching for solutions online but wasn't successful. Idk what i am doing wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your issue could be related to the `http` protocol, which can be considered as unsecured, especially in such context. Did you try with `https`?

Comment: First try with postman for api if this url is working properly

Comment: @Priya yes, I tried with Postman its's working there.

Comment: @NicolasCami Don't think so I can make Magento's REST API work on `https`. I couldn't find any way to make it work on `https`. Do you know any?

Comment: if you are using real device for testing then check you can access localhost from that device

Comment: @Priya No I am not using any real devices for testing. I am using AVM.

Comment: @KaushalDamania It would be nice if you can put your project on the github, so people can check on their end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what is wrong from the information you shared. But you can check my implementation for Magento 2 with React Native https://github.com/troublediehard/magento-react-native/blob/master/src/magento/index.js. It works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'll try with your implementation and let you know. Tbh even I am trying to figure out what's wrong. I just get the error that's all. I provided all information that I was aware of and thought is related to the problem.

Comment: I tried running your project but I get this error  [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OXVAHE6UCvO44CODQ0td8dOR-Gmxhzb6)

Comment: it says "FAILURE: Build failed with an exception" see the link

Comment: @KaushalDamania did you do 'react-native link react-native-vector-icons' ?

Comment: nope I only installed it by 'npm install --save react-native-vector-icons' in the project directory

Comment: @KaushalDamania it is in setup instructions in readme. Please try to follow it.

Comment: Ok! So, after some trouble I was able to run it without any compile time errors though I get a run time error saying `Native module VectorIconsModule tried to override VectorIconsModule for module name RNVectorIconsModule. If this was your intention, set canOverrideExistingModule=true
`

Here's a link to an image of the error. [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OXVAHE6UCvO44CODQ0td8dOR-Gmxhzb6)

Comment: @KaushalDamania please check https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/387

Comment: @KaushalDamania did you run it? If you need any help contact me via email. If it was helpful please vote for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this url

```
http://localhost/magento/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token
```

Source: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html

Comment: Nope, didn't help. Again the same error. Can someone try it on their PC?

Comment: Can you tell us your Android version on AVM?

Comment: It's 6.0 Marshmallow

Comment: Strange this issue looks same like https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17891